# Red mark over google play services lib in eclipse

Tags: android, google-play-services, eclipse-adt

I've followed sereval guides, copied the library folder into my workspace and then imported it into eclipse, I've cleaned it a dozen times and still there is this red exclamation mark that makes me unable to continue. As you can see there is no .jar in the bin folder and I have no idea why, the AndroidManifest.xml is blank, I don't know if it is supposed to. Please help, I've spent hours on this and I can't figure it out.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

For me, AndroidManifest.xml contains the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.google.android.gms"
    android:versionCode="4323030"
    android:versionName="4.3.23 (1069729-030)" >

   <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9"/>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Thanks but why don't I have it? What did I do wrong?